# How to create accessible for windows PC user Mac RDP alike host?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, remote-desktop

So on windows its quite simple to create RDP accessible PC. I wonder how to create accessible for windows PC user Mac RDP alike host. I want to be capable to see desctop, and run apps (alike teamviewer). I wonder what options I have for creation of such echosystem?

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X has a built-in VNC server; any VNC client can connect to that when configured.

On the Sharing preference pane:

[image: Configuring VNC access]

By checking the box in the `Computer Settings` dialog and entering a password, VNC clients can access this Mac to share the screen.